# NetBeans 7.4 beta and Sass on windows 7 x64

Tags: netbeans, sass, windows-7-x64

as in the title I'm trying to connect the newest NetBeans release with sass. I've pulled the sass-stable from github, unzipped it on harddrive and selected in NetBeans tha path to sass file.

While saving the .scss file I'm getting the error: `createProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid win application`

My guess is that I should set NetBeans to sass.bat file, but there is no such file in sass package. Plkease, can someone direct me in what should I do to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install Sass compiler using Ruby Gem, first install Ruby (from [here](http://rubyinstaller.org/)) and then run

```
gem install sass
```

After that, path to Sass compiler (in my  case) is

```
C:\Ruby200\bin\sass.bat
```

Comment: I believe it will the linked RubyInstaller for Windows